# SQL: Unable To Join These Two Tables (EAV Architechture, Magento)

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

The following query is getting me the entity_id and name columns

```
SELECT e.entity_id, eav.value AS name
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
  WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'name'
```

The following query is getting me the entity_id and price columns

```
SELECT e.entity_id, eav.value AS price
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
  WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'price'
```

I am unable to join these two, to get entity_id, name and price columns at once, could someone please help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT e.entity_id, eav.value AS name, eav2.value as price
  FROM catalog_product_entity e
  JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar eav
    ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
  JOIN eav_attribute ea
    ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
  JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal eav2
    ON e.entity_id = eav2.entity_id
  JOIN eav_attribute ea2
    ON eav2.attribute_id = ea2.attribute_id
 WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'name'
   and ea2.attribute_code = 'price'
```

Comment: thank you this worked, i was trying to use the where clause in a different way, so i was unable to figure it out.. now i got it.

Comment: Note that the inner joins mean that this will return rows for an entity that has both a "name" attribute and a "price" attribute. If either of those attributes is missing, a row for that entity will not be returned. (This isn't necessarily a problem; really depends on the specification... but one of the things about the EAV model is that it usually allows for some attribute values to be "missing".

Comment: Good to note. @brucekaushik if it is the case that something might not have a value for both attributes, make sure to also move the condition(s) from the WHERE clause into the ON clause(s) of the outer joins as appropriate, otherwise the rows will still be filtered out.